# uhd_packet_rx do not work

Tags: gnuradio, usrp

I was trying to set up packet communication using examples in gr-digital/examples/uhd_packet_tx and rx. uhd_packet_tx is doing fine, but on receiver side(uhd_packet_rx) is freeze when i check up the dialog button(). What should i do for running this examples ?